# bash error sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `/'

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed

I've write this script bash that must write a file with a specifical lines whit different
numbers (i.e.: "9.0E-8" ... ) so i must have the last file, after the for cycle, with
 "9.0E-11" respect "9.0E-7".

```
#!/bin/sh

touch IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java

for n in "9.0E-8" "9.0E-8" "9.0E-9" "9.0E-10" "9.0E-11"
do  
sed -i "21s/9\.0E-7/$n/" IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
javac IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
java IC_masslessPlanetesimal
done
```

Now the script must re-edit, compile and run the file.java and the code run without errors.
The problem now is:
 when i look into the file.java at the 21-th lines (there is the number the scrpt must changes) the scrpt edit only the first for-cycle because when it try to replace AGAIN the string whit the others one ("9.0E-9" etc...) the script can't find the last one !

first for step) 9e-7 -> 9e-8: script find 9e-7 and replace with n=9e-8
second for step) 9e-8 -> 9e-9: script DOESN'T FIND the 9e-8 string and can't change it !!!

So i must rewrite the for option to incorporate this modification.

Any guess please? :(

Comment: It LOOKS lie yopu're trying to change the 21st line in file IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java 5 times in the loop, first to 9.0E-7, then to 9.0E-8, etc. That makes absolutely no sense though so please tell us what you're really trying to do along with some sample input and expected output.

Comment: @ Ed Morton this is the first part of the bash, so every time i change the file i compile, run it, read it whit a program and take an output.

Comment: bash scripts are interpreted, not compiled. The point is though we cannot understand what it is you are trying to do from the description you have provided so far, posting the sample input and expected output is the minimum you need to do to help us understand what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `sed` commands is

```
[ address(es) ] command
```

21 is interpreted as the address, i.e. the line number. `/` is therefore treated as the command, hence the error.

What are you trying to do? If you want to replace 9.0e7 by $n on line 21, use

```
21s/9\.0E7/$n/
```

Answer (score 2):

Error is here:

```
sed -i "21/9.0E7/$n"
```

Since you haven't provided any sed command after `21`.

Did you forget `s` (substitute switch) in your sed command?

It should probably be:

```
sed -i "s/9.0E7/$n/"
```

OR may be this:

```
sed -i "21s/9.0E7/$n/"
```

Comment: no, this is not the error because when i put the `s` i recive the follow error message `sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command` . The 21 is the lines where i must change "9.0e-7" whit the string "n"

Comment: I suspect you might have some syntax error in your sed command now.